# Why do the <a> tags collapse into each other when position: absolute?

Tags: html, css

I am playing around with position: relative and absolute in a nav bar setting. Everything was going as expected until I set the `<a>` tags to position: absolute and the words collapsed into each other, their default padding between each word went bye bye!

I haven't really tried anything to remedy this because not even sure where to begin!

Why did this happen and how do I get them back to normal? (As well as be able to apply padding between each to spread them out?)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css"
      integrity="sha256-h20CPZ0QyXlBuAw7A+KluUYx/3pK+c7lYEpqLTlxjYQ="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  <title>Practice</title>
  <style>
    * {
      padding: 0%;
      margin: 0%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
    }

    header {
      position: relative;
      background: red;
      height: 150px;
      width: 100%;
    }

    i {
      position: absolute;
      top: 30px;
      left: 30px;
      color: #fff;
    }

    h1 {
      font-size: 36px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 45px;
      left: 100px;
    }

    a {
      color: #fff;
      text-decoration: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 60px;
      right: 100px;
    }

  </style>
</head>

<header>
    <i class="fas fa-user-astronaut fa-4x"></i>
    <h1>Hey Whatsup!</h1>
    <nav>
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
        <a href="#info">Info</a>
        <a href="#purchase">Purchase</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </nav>
</header>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `position:absolute;` is relative to `position:relative;`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the position to the parent element `<nav>` and not `<a>` tags.
I have shown it in the code below.

Here are some tips for you since you are a beginner.
Use position properties only when necessary. `<header>` should always come inside `<body>` tag. (as shown in the code)
`

```css
a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left:10px;
}

nav{
  position:absolute;
  top:60px; right:100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
      <i class="fas fa-user-astronaut fa-4x"></i>
      <h1>Hey Whatsup!</h1>
      <nav>
          <a href="#home">Home</a>
          <a href="#about">About</a>
          <a href="#info">Info</a>
          <a href="#purchase">Purchase</a>
          <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </nav>
  </header>
</body>
```

`

#### Understanding position absolute

If an element has absolute value, the element will respond to the dimensions of the entire document. For example, if you set it to top:0 and left: 0, the element will be placed at the top left corner of the browser window.
You may read more about it here. [CSS Positions](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/)

Answer (score 0):

> Why did this happen?

The issue is that you made all the `<a>` tag elements `absolute`.

This makes an element to be positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

> How do I get them back to normal?

Simply remove `position: absolute;` as whereas the respective positioning declarations i.e `top: 60px; right: 100px;` and you should be good to go.

**Example**

```
    a {
      color: #fff;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
```

> As well as be able to apply padding between each to spread them out?

As far as spreading them out is concerned, you could simply add `margin-right:---` to your links.
i.e

```
    nav a {
      color: #fff;
      text-decoration: none;
      margin-right: 1em;
    }

   nav a:last-child {
     margin-right: 0;
   }
```

Comment: Thank you! I took a break and went for a walk, halfway through realized my mistake was putting position: absolute under a {} instead of nav {} Thank you for verifying :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `a`, you may set positioning for their parent element (`nav`).

```
nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  right: 100px;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/6st0129p/

Answer (score 0):

Great to see you get starting with Html/css.

The issue here is you have given position:absolute for each of the elements ( icon tag , h1 tag and a tag ). Absolute positioned items, is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport ).

Position property - https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

So we usually don't give position: absolute for the items in a nav. You can use flexbox to position the contents of a header adjacent to each other.

Flexbox - https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

So you can remove position absolute from all the items, and give a display:flex to the header, then you will have items  adjacent to each other

Its okay if you were just trying out how they would look while positioning, then it's okay. I hope you get an idea from this.

All the best !